# MySQL process hogging CPU, what does this process do?

Tags: mysql, process, cpanel, whm

/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server188.serveer.com.err --open-files-limit=50000 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/server188.serveer.com.pid

this process is hogging alot of CPU, 30-35%, what does it do and how do i keep the usage low? the server is idle without any scripts/sql running.

these are the settings

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=107374182
open_files_limit=50000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128GB
max_connections=500
key_buffer_size=64G
query_cache_size = 128MB
query_cache_limit = 128MB
```

server:

256GB RAM
quad 12xprocessors

Comment: That's the MySQL server. It only runs in response to queries by clients. It shouldn't be hogging the CPU if there aren't any programs sending queries. Go into `mysql` and use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see the queries that it's receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Right. Check your which databases is using high CPU on your server through mysql **SHOW PROCESSLIST** command  and try to optimizes your MySQL services with the mysqltuner scripts.